# Angular test failing because of Custom Filter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a Pipe in the search bar for Table. I am getting the following error:

```
      The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="l[ERROR ->]et i of tutors | filter : searchText" name="tutors_list">
          <td>{{i.name}}</td>
```

I have added the filter in declaration of `app.module.ts`.

Here is my custom filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string) {
   if (searchText === undefined) return items;

   return items.filter(function(i){
    if( i.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    {  return i;}
    else if( i.department.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    {  return i;}
    else if( i.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
    {  return i;}
   });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your App module, include your `FilterPipe` class in `declarations` array.

```
// App.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    FilterPipe // This i what you are missing.
  ],
...
export class AppModule {
   ...
}
```

For unit tests, this has to be declared within the TestBed. Something like,

```
...

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FilterPipe ], // Declare your filter here
              ...
    });

...
```